# How to test a function which returns a promise $q?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

**My JS File:**

```
case "launch": helper.urlLaunch("http://www.google.com").then(function (){start();});
```

**Definition of urlLaunch**

```
urlLaunch: function (url) {
            //...
            return $q.when();
        },
```

**Unit tests**

```
it("should test helper launch url", function() {
            spyOn(helper, "urlLaunch").and.callFake(function(){});
            mySvc.purchase( Url: PURCHASE_URL }); //this calls the "launch" case given above
            $httpBackend.flush();
            expect(helper.urlLaunch).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
```

But this gives me an error **"TypeError: plan.apply is not a function"**

Any ideas what am I missing here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your urlLaunch function is supposed to return a promise, but you mock it with a fake function that doesn't return anything. So the code using the returned promise will in fact receive `undefined`. That can't work.

You need to return a promise from the spied function:

```
spyOn(helper, "urlLaunch").and.returnValue($q.when('some fake result'));
mySvc.purchase( Url: PURCHASE_URL });
$scope.$apply(); // to actually resolve the fake promise, and trigger the call of the callbacks

// ...
```